# not getting radio button value in javascript

Tags: javascript, radio-button

In my application I am trying to get value of radio button but some how not able to get it.

my html is

```
<div style="border-bottom: 5px Solid #800080;">
    <input type="radio" value="0 " name="routeSelect" checked="checked">Route 1</div>
<br>
<div style="border-bottom: 5px Solid #000080;">
    <input type="radio" value="1 " name="routeSelect">Route 2</div>
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="alert(getRadioValue());" value="Which?" />
```

my js is

```
function getRadioValue() {

    var group = document.getElementsByName("routeSelect");

    for (var i = 0; i < group.length; i++) {
        if (group[i].checked) {
            return group[i].value;
        }
    }

    return '';
}
```

Here Is link : http://jsfiddle.net/aX89G/

can any one tell me what is wrong I am doing

Comment: Please don't delete your question after it was answered.

Comment: Inline javascript screws you like that. Try: http://jsfiddle.net/aX89G/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is fine but the `getRadioValue` function isn't found, it's currently wrapped in a function which is called on load, you must choose `No wrap - in <head>` in the menu at the left of jsfiddle's window.

This is equivalent to putting the code in a `script` element in the `head` of your page.

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/nD6Cs/)

Alternatively, you could separate your javascript from your HTML this way :

```
<input id=butt type="button" value="Which?" />

<script>
    document.getElementById('butt').onclick=function(){
       alert(getRadioValue());
    });
</script>
```

This is usually considered cleaner and easier to maintain.